# OSError: [WinError 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am facing some problem while running a python3 code.

Here is my part of the code in which I am facing error.

```
try:
        track_no = int(input("Enter the song number you want to download(0 to download all): "))

        resp = input("Do you want to create folder '%s'?(y)" %movie.text) 
        if resp.strip().lower() in ('y', 'yes'):
            dir_path  = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), movie.text) 
            if os.path.isdir(dir_path):
                print ("Directory '%s' already exist. Skipping..."%(dir_path))
            else:
                os.mkdir(dir_path)
        else:
            dir_path = os.getcwd()
        if track_no == 0:
            for song in songs:
                #call downloader function
                download_song(song, dir_path)
        else:
            download_song(songs[track_no - 1], dir_path)
        print ('Download complete')

    except (ValueError, IndexError):
        print ('Invalid input. Exiting...')
        sys.exit(1)
else:
    print ("Movie not found")
```

I am facing the following error.

```
main()
  File "song.py", line 118, in main
    os.mkdir(dir_path)
OSError: [WinError 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect: 'C:\\Users\\Acnovate IN Admin\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36-32\\\nWanted\n'
```

I am new to python and working on some script. Please anyone suggest me that what is the wrong in the above part of my code.

Comment: what error are you facing ? please post your error too.

Comment: You are not showing us how `movie.text` is defined so we have no way to find out why it's wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see at the end of the line in the traceback regarding the incorrect syntax in your directory name, there are line feeds `\n`. You can solve this by stripping any whitespace characters from `movie.text`.

Use this:

```
dir_path  = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), movie.text.strip())
```

If your string in `movie.text` might contain even more line feeds use this.

```
dir_path  = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), movie.text.replace('\n', ''))
```

Comment: Still i am getting this error                                                                       Error occured: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'C:\\Users\\Acnovate IN Admin\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36-32\\\n\n\xa0Download\n.mp3'

Comment: This is not possible. The string still contains new line characters... `'\n\n\xa0Download\n.mp3'`... I see three `\n` in there. Try the method `replace`.